# Как сделать доступ к элементам матрицы по двойному указателю?

Tags: c

Как сделать доступ к элементам матрицы по двойному указателю?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Пусть задан указатель на массив:

```
int *array;
```

Тогда для массива размерностью [l x w x h] элемент на позиции (a, b, c) будет доступен по смещению

```
element = *(array + a * (w * h) + b * (h) + c)
```

Или через разыменовывание:

```
int array[l][w][h];

element = *( *( *(array + a) + b) + c)
```

Comment: у меня есть задание.работа с матрицами
C=2(A+B)*B
ниже идет прога. Мне дали задание (1)найти произвидение отрицатильных эл-тов матрицы,используя подпрограмму,возвращающую значение. 2)Доступ к эл-там матрицы по указанию.) можете исправить код,Э?

Comment: @Виталя: деньги за проект пополам?